# Iterative decoding

Tags: c#, iteration, decoding

So, I have a cipher that I would need to break. I have the key, but the problem is that every number in a cipher corresponds to three or two letters. For example, if we had the cipher '12', and we know that '1' corresponds to either 'A', 'J' or 'S', and '2' corresponds to 'B', 'K' or 'T', we would need to output all possible combinations, so: 'AB', 'AK', 'AT', 'JB', 'JK', 'JT', 'SB', 'SK', 'ST'. How would I go around doing this in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you already have some code to show?

Comment: Sorry, no, I only have the code that parses the input, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: Well you need some datastructure that keeps your translation (1 -> A, J, S). The calculation of possible combinations should be pretty simple if you code it as a recursive function. You should start implementing a bit, and if you have a specific problem ask a question here (since this question seems to be pretty broad)

Comment: That's kind of the point to my question, I have the idea of how I would need to do it. I, on the other hand, do not have the required capabilites to think of how to do this in an efficient way.

Comment: How about you implement it then your way first? Refactoring and making stuff faster can always be done afterwards, especially when people here can look at some code.

Comment: I have phrased my response very poorly, sorry for that. I know what I would need to do. I do not know how I would implement it code-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ you can use following code:

```
var input = "12";

var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
mappings.Add("1", new string[] { "A", "J", "S" });
mappings.Add("2", new string[] { "B", "K", "T" });

var result = input.Select(c => mappings[c.ToString()]).CartesianProduct();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", item.ToArray()));
}
```

It uses the [CartesianProduct extension method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) from [Eric Lipperts blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/)

Cant get much easier

Comment: This potentionally could work, although it produces an 'OutOfMemoryException'. Any idea how to make this less memory-intensive? By the way, I'm building for x64 architecture on an x64 system with 8GB of RAM installed.

Comment: @CrAzYPiLoT: lose the "ToArray". That causes the entire query result to be realized all at once in a big block of memory. There's no need for that.

Comment: Removed the ToArray(). I used it just for better debugging visibility.

Comment: Thanks guys, although I solved another way, this'll come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to create a cross join :

```
char[][] cl1 = { new[] {'A','J','S'}, new[] {'B','K','T'}, new[] {'C','L','U'} ......};

int offsetchar1 = 0;
int offsetchar2 = 1;
var j = (from c1 in cl1[offsetchar1]
          from c2 in cl1[offsetchar2]
          select
          c1.ToString() + c2.ToString()).ToArray();
```

To add third char :

```
  int offsetchar3 = 2;
  var k = (from j1 in j
          from c3 in cl1[offsetchar3]
          select
          j1 + c3.ToString()).ToArray();
```